# failing to persist geometry object to oracle using hibernate spatial

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, oracle10g, hibernate-spatial

I'm using **Spring** with **Hibernate Spatial** 5.0.12 and trying to persist a `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry` object to an **Oracle** database with `SDO_GEOMETRY` column but get this exception when trying to save it to the db:

```
ORA-00932: Inconsistent datatypes: expected MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY got BINARY
```

I haven't found this problem anywhere else and have no idea how to solve it as I'm new to hibernate.

This is the entity I'm trying to save:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DETECTED_OBJECTS")
public class DetectedObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DETECTED_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "detected_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "DETECTED_SEQ"_
    private Long id;
    private Geometry polygon;

    public DetectedObject(){}

    public DetectedObject(Coordinate[] coordinates){
    this.polygon = new GeometryFactory().createPolygon(coordinates);
    }
}
```

And this is my hibernate config:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.properties.provider_class = org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format-sql = true
```

And the actual line that throws the exception:

```
detectedObjectRepository.save(detectedObject)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add the below configs in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect

spring.datasource.type=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
```

If this doesn't work, use `geolatte` library and below properties in model:

```
private Point<G2D> point;
private Polygon<G2D> polygon;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Solution was to explicitly tell spring I'm using a spatial dialect with hibernate by changing this line:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

to this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect
```